# How to partially modify the swagger springfox Example Value?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

How can I partially modify the swagger springfox "Example Value" displayed in swagger UI, to only show required property for requestBody? For instance consider below code

```java
//BoxController.java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/box")
public class BoxController{
   @PostMapping
   public Box createBox(@RequestBody BoxModel boxModel){
       ...
   }
}

//BoxDTO.java
public class BoxDTO{

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    public CustomerId customerId;

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    public String name;

    public int boxId;

    public Dimensions dimensions;
}
```

**On the swagger-ui.html page under the endpoint description "Example Value"**
What I am currently seeing for POST as well as GET:

```
{
    customerId: {...},
    name: "string",
    boxId: 0,
    dimensions: {...}
}
```

What I would like to see for POST: (only the required properties of the request body)

```
{
    customerId: {...},
    name: "string",
}
```

What I would like to see for GET: (all properties from the model)

```
{
    customerId: {...},
    name: "string",
    boxId: 0,
    dimensions: {...}
}
```

Besides example value there is Model where I can see the required property but it is not in JSON format. 
I also know a way of adding the Example Value on the param using @ApiParam(examples=...{JSON sample}) but in this case I would have to manually put entire JSON sample.

I would like to know if there is any way to specify in the Controller class; to only display the required properties of the request body; in the "Example Value" automatically?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using Data Transfer Objects (DTO) to decouple your model and your rest API

Comment: @Ckram yes so consider the BoxModel a DTO, sorry for bad naming I will update it as BoxDTO. I cannot share the actual code so I came up with an example of the scenario.

Comment: @Ckram do you mean I should use a different DTO for PUT and different DTO for POST?

Comment: You can do that, or you could also try to use `@Valid` on your `@PostMapping` argument and swagger should display your field as required if they are. It may be enough for you